# Developer Console: Keep constantly open without stopping producing debug logs

Tags: developer-console, debugging, debug-logs

If i open developer console and leave it open without any activity, i get a message after (e.g. 1hr) that
"Your Developer Console session has been idle. To resume logging and listening for updates, click Resume below or click Debug -> Resume at a later time."
[image]

However, i want to keep it open in order to get the debug logs generated. Is there any way to achieve that? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you want to collect your debug logs, you don't need the developer console.
You should [create a trace flag](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.code_add_users_debug_log.htm&type=5) for your user (or the user you want to log):

1. From Setup, enter *Debug Logs* in the Quick Find box, then click **Debug Logs**
2. Click **New**.

   - In "Traced Entity Type" keep *User*
   - In "Traced Entity Name" select your user.
   - Set the time period during which you want to collect logs.
   - Set a debug level according your needs keeping in mind that a finer level  results in a bigger file size.
3. Click **Save**.

If you're going to set an extended period for your trace flag or a finest debug level, you should take in account the following limits:

- Each debug log must be 20 MB or smaller. Debug logs that are larger than 20 MB are reduced in size by removing older log lines.
- Monitoring debug logs are retained for seven days.
- If you generate more than 1,000 MB of debug logs in a 15-minute window, your trace flags are disabled.
- When your org accumulates more than 1,000 MB of debug logs, Salesforce prevents users in the org from adding or editing trace flags. To add or edit trace flags so that you can generate more logs after you reach the limit, delete some debug logs.

Comment: Ruben, thanks for the detailed response! :)